# C++ Combining two zero terminated strings?

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

So I am doing a question where I have to join two zero terminated strings, the first contains a word, and the second is empty and twice the size of the original array. I was able to get this working using the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str1[] = "test";
    char str2[(sizeof(str1)-1)*2];

    char *p;
    int count = 0;

    for(p = str1; *p != 0; p++) {
        str2[count] = *p;
        count++;
    }
    cout << str2;
}
```

However I have to use a function with the following prototype

```
char *combine(char *a);
```

So I tried this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char *copy_and_reverse(char *a) {


char str2[8];
    int count = 0;
    char* b = str2;

    for(a; *a != 0; a++) {
        str2[count] = *a;
        count++;
    }
    
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "test";

    char *a;
    a = str1;

    char* b = copy_and_reverse(a);

    for(b; *b != 0; b++) {
        cout << *b;
    }
}
```

But it does not work (it is printing the string but it's printing a few random characters after it), I'm getting so confused with the pointers, can anyone help me out with this?

Edit: here is the question I am trying to answer

> Write a function in C++ that takes as a `char *` style zero terminated string and returns a `char*` string twice the length of the input. The first half of the returned string should contain a copy of the contents of the original array. The second half of the string should contain the contents of the original string in reverse order.
>
> The function should have the following prototype:
>
> ```
> char *copy_and_reverse(char* a);
> ```
>
> Note: you should not use any library functions (e.g from `string.h`).

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. Nowhere do you have two zero-terminated strings. Your first code copies a string (like `strcpy`) but doesn't terminate the result, yielding undefined behavior. Then you're talking about `combine` (unclear what that's supposed to do), and your final example contains `copy_and_reverse` (there's no reversing in there). You said you're doing a question. What's the actual text of the exercise?

Comment: Other than `cout`, this really isn't C++. This is C. You should change the tag.

Comment: @melpomene There's no point in messing with `char*` in C++ when you have `std::string`, is what I'm saying...

Comment: @melpomene: Umm, in what sense? It's valid C++, yes, but it's not really a question about C++.

Comment: @c650 `#include <iostream>`, `using namespace std`, `cout << ...` aren't valid C is what I'm saying.

Comment: @melpomene is 'char str1[] = "test"' not a zero-terminated string? The method has reversing in the name because I have to do that also, I just want to get this working first, I will add in the text of the question

Comment: @melpomene and you're right in that sense, but those utilities aren't relevant to the OP's problem at hand.. and the OP wouldn't have his problem if he were actually using C++ strings which would be concatenated with `+`.

Comment: @einpoklum How so? `char` arrays and zero-terminated strings are part of C++, even if you don't like it.

Comment: Also, @DavidFarrelly, do you want to combine strings or copy a string?

Comment: @DavidFarrelly It is a zero-terminated string.

Comment: `std::string a = "whatever"; std::string b = "something else"; std::string c = a + b;` There. Concatenated strings. Reversing: `for (int i = 0; i > c.length()/2; ++i) std::swap(c[i], c[c.length()-i-1]);`

Comment: "Note: you should not use any library funtions (e.g from string.h)" `string.h` is not C++!

Comment: @c650 Yes, it is.

Comment: @melpomene no, `#include <cstring>` is.

Comment: @c650 Formally this question is about C++, even if it's not C++ style. There is no sense in putting C tag on a question with C++ code even if it's written in C style. Also, he is obviously using `char *` for learing purposes. If you use C++ it doesn't mean that you don't need to know how stuff works under the hood.

Comment: @c650 All 3 of `<string.h>`, `<cstring>`, `<string>` are C++.

Comment: @melpomene, sorry I read your comment wrong, the reason I didn't define two strings is because in the function I have to pass in the pointer and I don't know how to get the actual string from that pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two big problems in your `copy_and_reverse` code.

1. After copying the input string, you are not terminating the result. This means `str2` is not a valid string. Fix:

   ```
       str2[count] = '\0';  // after the loop
   ```
2. `copy_and_reverse` returns a pointer to a local variable (`str2`). After the function returns, all its local variables are gone, and `main` is dealing with an invalid pointer. To fix this, either use static memory (e.g. by declaring `str2` as `static` or making it a global variable) or dynamic memory (allocate storage with `new[]` (or `malloc()`)). Both approaches have their disadvantages.

Minor stuff:

- `variable;` does nothing (see `for (a; ...)`, `for (b; ...)`).
- `str2` isn't big enough for the final result. `str1` is 5 bytes long (`'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'`), so `char str2[8]` is sufficient for now, but in the end you want to allocate `length * 2 + 1` bytes for your result.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that this will suit your needs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char* copy_and_reverse(char* a);

static int strlen(char *c); // self-implemented

int main(void) {

    char *a = "some string";

    char *b = copy_and_reverse(a);

    printf("%s", b);

    free(b);

    return 0;
}


static char* copy_and_reverse(char* a) {

    int n = strlen(a);

    char *b = new char[n * 2 + 1]; // get twice the length of a and one more for \0

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { // does copying and reversing
        b[i] = a[i];
        b[i+n] = a[n-i-1];
    }

    b[2 * n] = '\0'; // null out last one

    return b;
}

static int strlen(char *c) {
    char *s = c;
    while( *s++ );

    return s-c-1;
}
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, You can't use `string.h`'s impl as per the OP. If that's why you downvoted, reverse pls

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: Don't use C-style casts in C++.

Comment: @melpomene it compiles though :)

Comment: @melpomene but I changed the casting anyway

Comment: Why use `malloc` here instead of `new`?